# Using for expression inside xpath expression lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

Is there any way to use a for expression with the `.xpath` method in `lxml`?

If I have an xml like

```
<DataGrid>
   <row>
      <description>Map to blank.</description>
      <rule />
   </row>
   <row>
      <description>The Vehicle Identification Number.</description>
      <rule>PRINT VIN</rule>
   </row>
</DataGrid>
```

Is there any way to run this xpath expression directly using `lxml`

`for $var in //DataGrid/row return concat($var/rule/text(), '%%', $var/description/text())`

I'm expecting to get a list with two strings as the result: `["'%%Map to blank.'", "'PRINT VIN%%The Vehicle Identification Number.'"]`

Running `root.xpath('for $var in //DataGrid/row return concat($var/rule/text(), '%%', $var/description/text())')` results in this traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XPathEvalError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-a37be007325f> in <module>
----> 1 root.xpath("for $var in //DataGrid/row return concat($var/rule/text(), '%%', $var/description/text())")

src/lxml/etree.pyx in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath()

src/lxml/xpath.pxi in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__()

src/lxml/xpath.pxi in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result()

XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Alternatively - is lxml not the right library for this? or is there any other library that I can run these xpath expressions directly on an XML file?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: How do I get the output I desire? I'm not able to run the xpath expressions on the XML. It works for simple expressions, but something like ForExpr doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you try with python for loop

Comment: not sure how that helps though. Is it not possible to run arbitrary xpath 1.0 expressions using lxml? nothing in the documentation mentioned any such cases. My use case involves having users input the xpath expressions (and they can input any expression)

Comment: lxml supports XPath 1.0. The `for` expressions were added in XPath 2.0.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize `for` expressions were added in XPath 2.0 - Thanks! i'll scour the web for a library that can help with evaluating XPath 2.0 expressions

Comment: @mzjn Do you want to post that as an answer? and I will accept it

Comment: You might be interested in the commercial product Saxon/C, which has a Python API and supports XPath 3.1. https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it should be doable with lxml:

```
dg = """[your xml above]"""
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.XML(dg)

my_vars = doc.xpath('//row')
for a_var in my_vars:
    print(a_var.xpath("concat(./rule/text(),' %% ', ./description/text())"))
```

Output:

```
%% Map to blank.
PRINT VIN %% The Vehicle Identification Number.
```

Comment: My use case is that users will be running their own expressions to evaluate. The problem here was that I didn't realize that lxml (and libxml2) only supported XPath 1.0 syntax and `for .. return` expressions were introduced with XPath 2.0.

Comment: @wkgrcdsam Are the user required to use `for ... return` expression or can they use any xpath expression?

Comment: They can use any xpath expression. the project is in a Proof of Concept phase, i.e. flexible requirements. So if we need to restrict it to XPath 1.0 for ease, we can do that.

Comment: @wkgrcdsam Interesting. Since you are at the PoC stage, I, in your place, would actually try to go the other way around: xpath/xquery 3.1 (the current version) is far more powerful than 1.0. If you are restricted to python (or php or nodejs), you will be stuck with 1.0, for most part. But if not, then depending on the source and amount of xml data, you might want to go with a dedicated xml database (like BaseX) which has 3.1 support. Another option would be xidel, a cli utility. In either case, for users to write their own expressions would require them to be fully familiar with xpath.